# Is there a way to "pad" the text once a UITextField becomes active

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

Is there a way to have the text start in a different location other than the textfield when activated? I'm specifically trying to get it to start a few points to the right of the image that is the UITextField. Thanks

Comment: I'll answer my own question. A simple UIImageView with the image needed under a UITextField positioned where I want the text to start.

Comment: or you could use `leftView`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at overriding UITextField's textRectForBounds method.